# flock in Perl: Bad file descriptor

Tags: perl, locking, flock

i use Perl v5.10.1, and have next part of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Fcntl qw(LOCK_EX LOCK_NB);
my ( $fh, $path );
$path = q{/var/run/}. time() .q{.pid};
sysopen $fh, $path, O_RDWR|O_CREAT || die qq{Cannot open "$path": $!\n};
flock ( $fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) || die qq{pid "$path" already locked: $!\n};
```

when i try to run it:

> pid "/var/run/1392394505.pid" already locked: Bad file descriptor

What's wrong with it? Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the reason behind a variable lock file name.

Comment: @ikegami is there some reference for bitwise flags and `open`?

Comment: @mpapec, `man 2 open` (quoted above), and either the same or `perldoc -f open` depending on whether you mean the system call or the Perl function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That means `$fh` doesn't contain a file handle. That's because you incorrectly checked if `sysopen` succeeded. Specifically, you are suffering from a precedence issue.

```
sysopen $fh, $path, O_RDWR|O_CREAT || die qq{Cannot open "$path": $!\n};
```

means

```
sysopen $fh, $path, ( O_RDWR|O_CREAT || die qq{Cannot open "$path": $!\n} );
```

which means

```
sysopen $fh, $path, O_RDWR|O_CREAT;
```

Use `or` instead of `||`. You could also use parens. Or both. Fixed:

```
sysopen(my $fh, $path, O_RDWR|O_CREAT)
   or die qq{Can't open "$path": $!\n};
```

Two other errors: 1) You never import `O_RDWR` and `O_CREAT`, so you're actually passing a junk string for `sysopen`'s third argument. (Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!) 2) Your error message is incorrect. You say it's already locked even when it isn't. Fixed:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Fcntl qw( LOCK_EX LOCK_NB O_RDWR O_CREAT );
my $path = q{/var/run/}. time() .q{.pid};
sysopen(my $fh, $path, O_RDWR|O_CREAT)
   or die qq{Cannot open "$path": $!\n};
if (!flock($fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
   die qq{Can't lock "$path": $!\n} if !$!{EWOULDBLOCK};
   die qq{pid already locked\n};
}
```

Comment: You *always* need to *import* them. Fixed.

Comment: you can also write `use Fcntl qw(:flock);` to import the LOCK_XXX constants

Answer (score 0):

solved

there are no permissions to write in /var/run to this user..
sudo %scriptname% works ok